# Can viewDidLoad get called before 'init' of a viewController is fully executed?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

What is the full sequence events in terms of how a view controller loaded into memory from init to viewDidLoad?

If you do something like:

```
TabControllerClass *cc = [[TabControllerClass alloc] initWithCustomData:something];
```

Can the class's viewDidLoad get invoked before reaching the end of the custom init method, 'initWithCustomData'?

```
- (id)initWithCustomData:(NSString *)something
{
    if (self = [super init])
    {
        // A bunch of other initialization happens
    }

    // Would you reach here before 'viewDidLoad' is invoked?
    return self;
}
```

where my TabControllerClass inherits from UITabBarController.

Comment: Do you implement loadView or do you use a nib to construct the actual view? I am not sure whether it matters though, but if you use initWithNib: (which you obviously don't) the matter is probably different than if you construct the view programmatically.

Comment: There's no nib loading and this class inherits from UITabBarController.

Comment: Uh, you're not supposed to subclass UITabBarController. That might explain the issue (as Alexsander wrote, your method probably isn't the designated initializer then). If you have to overwrite certain methods of UITabBarController use Categories.

Comment: I'm writing NSLog output to trace this and it really does appear that the viewDidLoad is invoked before reaching the end of the 'init' method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume not. I mean, how can any method be called before the controller is correctly allocated and initialized? However, you may find that your `-[ControllerClass initWithCustomData]` initializer isn't the *designated* initializer, which **could** explain why it isn't being called.

Comment: Figured it out. Invoking [super init] calls initWithNib, which in turn invokes viewDidLoad.